# Create Data Frame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a data frame from the data below using pandas. I need the data from the first list... specifically 'equity' and 'unrealizedPnl' When I use the columns method I just get the results from the 'free' 'used' and 'total' section.

```
    {'info': {'retCode': '0', 'retMsg': 'OK', 'result': {'list': [{'coin': 'BTC', 'equity': '0.05461474', 'walletBalance': '0.09951146', 'positionMargin': '0.06973251', 'availableBalance': '0.02977895', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0.00025718', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '-0.04489672', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0.05209768', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'ETH', 'equity': '0.92655684', 'walletBalance': '0.9210418', 'positionMargin': '0.06940536', 'availableBalance': '0.82964984', 'orderMargin': '0.0219866', 'occClosingFee': '0.00000601', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0.00551504', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0.63929684', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'EOS', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'XRP', 'equity': '11.73802937', 'walletBalance': '11.73802937', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '11.73802937', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '-319.12197063', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'USDT', 'equity': '913.78491494', 'walletBalance': '5141.98448687', 'positionMargin': '4562.26040098', 'availableBalance': '526.5045238', 'orderMargin': '53.21956209', 'occClosingFee': '168.00001152', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '-4228.19957193', 'cumRealisedPnl': '4047.21107387', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'DOT', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'LTC', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'BIT', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'USDC', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '0', 'accountMM': '0'}, {'coin': 'ADA', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}, {'coin': 'MANA', 'equity': '0', 'walletBalance': '0', 'positionMargin': '0', 'availableBalance': '0', 'orderMargin': '0', 'occClosingFee': '0', 'occFundingFee': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '0', 'cumRealisedPnl': '0', 'givenCash': '0', 'serviceCash': '0', 'accountIM': '', 'accountMM': ''}]}, 'retExtInfo': {}, 'time': '1678492965544'}, 'BTC': {'free': 0.02977895, 'used': 0.06973251, 'total': 0.09951146}, 'ETH': {'free': 0.82964984, 'used': 0.09139196, 'total': 0.9210418}, 'EOS': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'XRP': {'free': 11.73802937, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 11.73802937}, 'USDT': {'free': 526.5045238, 'used': 4615.47996307, 'total': 5141.98448687}, 'DOT': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'LTC': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'BIT': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'USDC': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'ADA': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'MANA': {'free': 0.0, 'used': 0.0, 'total': 0.0}, 'free': {'BTC': 0.02977895, 'ETH': 0.82964984, 'EOS': 0.0, 'XRP': 11.73802937, 'USDT': 526.5045238, 'DOT': 0.0, 'LTC': 0.0, 'BIT': 0.0, 'USDC': 0.0, 'ADA': 0.0, 'MANA': 0.0}, 'used': {'BTC': 0.06973251, 'ETH': 0.09139196, 'EOS': 0.0, 'XRP': 0.0, 'USDT': 4615.47996307, 'DOT': 0.0, 'LTC': 0.0, 'BIT': 0.0, 'USDC': 0.0, 'ADA': 0.0, 'MANA': 0.0}, 'total': {'BTC': 0.09951146, 'ETH': 0.9210418, 'EOS': 0.0, 'XRP': 11.73802937, 'USDT': 5141.98448687, 'DOT': 0.0, 'LTC': 0.0, 'BIT': 0.0, 'USDC': 0.0, 'ADA': 0.0, 'MANA': 0.0}}
```

I tried using every pandas method I know and it has got me perplexed.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Please learn the basic data structures of python.

you have a dictionary nested with lists and other dictionaries.
`data={'info': {'r...`
with `data.keys()` you get the keys of your dictionary

```
> dict_keys(['info', 'BTC', 'ETH', 'EOS', 'XRP', 'USDT', 'DOT', 'LTC',
> 'BIT', 'USDC', 'ADA', 'MANA', 'free', 'used', 'total'])
```

this way you can find out that 'data["info"]["result"]["list"]' gives you your list

creating a pandas dataframe can work like this. you did not mention what names your columns should have.
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you want to read is in the `['info']['result']['list']` dict, so just use:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data['info']['result']['list'])
```